# Problemas con => prompt y ventana emergente a la vez en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5, ventana, prompt

de primeras muchas gracias por ayudarme con mi problema.
Estoy intentando hacer este ejercicio:

- Abra una nueva ventana no redimensionable.
- Hacer una función y dentro de esa función:

  ```
     Escribir en la nueva ventana <h3>Ejemplo de Ventana Nueva</h3>
     Pide mas cosas (resumen)
  ```
- Y ahora fuera del código de la función que siga haciendo lo siguiente:

  ```
     Que escriba en la ventana principal <h1>TAREA DWEC03</H2><HR />
  ```
- Mediante el método prompt:

  ```
     Que solicite: introduzca su nombre y apellidos.
     Pide mas cosas (resumen)
  ```
- Una vez solicitado esos datos imprimirá en la ventana principal:

  ```
         Buenos días XXXXX
         Tu nombre tiene XX caracteres, incluidos espacios.
  ```

Bien espero que se entienda. La cosa es que quiero sacar el prompt y la ventana emergente a la vez, pero o me sale el prompt primero o la ventana emergente dando como resultado la frase:

```
             Buenos días null.
```

Porque claro no he podido introducir nada en el prompt ya que este no salta por la ventana emergente.
Por lo que he leído el Blur no funciona Chrome para quitar el foco de la ventana emergente y ponerlo en la ventana principal y así tal vez salte el prompt a la vez que la ventana.

[image: Imagen de la situación:]

Muchas gracias pego código por aquí:

```
**<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>DWEC03</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
         
        *//Creamos un objeto subVentana para abrir esa ventana emergente con el metodo
        //open() ponemos que no sea redimensionable y el tamaño de altura y ancho fijos.*
      var subVentana = window.open(
        "",
        "nueva",
        "resizable=0, width=700, height=500"
      );
      
      *//Realizamos la función que nos piden para pintar dentro de la ventana "<h3>Ejemplo de Ventana Nueva</h3>"*
      var funcionTarea = function() {
        subVentana.document.open();
        subVentana.document.write("<h3>Ejemplo de Ventana Nueva</h3>");
        *//URL completa nos pide el ejercicio la escribimos dentro y usamos el writeln para hacer un salto de linea*
        subVentana.document.writeln(
          "URL completa: " + subVentana.document.URL + "<br>"
        );
        *//Protocolo utilizado:*
        subVentana.document.writeln(
          "Protocolo utilizado: " + subVentana.location.protocol + "<br>"
        );
        *// appCodeName => Cadena que contine el nombre del cliente del navegador*
        subVentana.document.writeln(
          "Nombre en código del navegador: " +
            subVentana.navigator.appCodeName +
            "<br>"
        );
        *// navigator.javaEnabled => Metodo que devuelve true si el cliente permita la
        //utilización de java en caso contrario devuelve false*
        if (subVentana.navigator.javaEnabled) {
          subVentana.document.writeln("Java SI disponible en esta ventana<br>");
        } else {
          subVentana.document.writeln("Java NO disponible en esta ventana<br>");
        }
        *// Abrir el iframe:*
        subVentana.document.writeln(
          '<iframe src="https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Portada" width="800" height="600"></iframe>'
        );
        
      };
       *//Llamamos a la función:*
       funcionTarea();
        *//Ventana principal:
        /*Información de blur => https://informaticapc.com/tutorial-javascript/ventana-del-navegador-web.php*/*
        
    
      document.write("<h1>TAREA DWEC03</H2><HR />");
      *//Pedimos todo lo que solicita la tarea a través del promt:*
      var nombre = window.prompt("Introduzca su nombre y apellidos.");
      */*var dia = window.prompt("Introduzca su DIA de nacimiento.");
      var mes = window.prompt("Introduzca su MES de nacimiento.");
      var anho =window.prompt("Introduzca su AÑO de nacimieno.");*/*
    
     
      document.writeln("Buenos días " + nombre + "<br>");
       
      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>**
```

Comment: No creo que se pueda ya que haría en conflicto con el CORS. De todos modos, sigo sin entender el objetivo.

Comment: Gracias es que es un poco lioso, tal vez es por eso que no se pueda hacer. Al abrir la página se lanza esa ventana emergente y a la vez tengo puesto que salga un prompt: pidiendo le al usuario su nombre, para que de como resultado: Buenos días Pepito por ejemplo. Pero o me sale la ventana y no me deja hacerlo por eso da null. o si pongo el prompt antes me sale el prompt y hasta que no lo rellene no me sale la ventana. La cosa es si puede salir a la vez?

Comment: ¿El prompt tiene que salir de la primera ventana o de la segunda?